registered callback does not match with the provided url
I configure a distributed WSO2 API-M deployment. And use I WSO2 identity server as a Key Manager in my setup. There is no issue in run time. But try to login WSO2 identity server using URL "https://km.wso2.com:9443/console" then show this error "Registered callback does not match with the provided URL " in webpage.

wso2-is-login-error
How can I fix this issue at the deployment level by editing the configuration or adding new settings?
